# Groovy NoSuchMethodException error

Tags: groovy, jsr223

I'm trying to use Groovy with JSR223. I have one file for groovy script that is evaluated at the program start.

Any idea what could be wrong ? I am using JDK 6 and groovy-all-2.3.0.jar

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.GetObjectName() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [param1, param2]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.invokeImpl(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:396)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.invokeFunction(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:192)
        at GroovyTest.main(GroovyTest.java:61)
```

Groovy code:

```
def GetObjectName(java.lang.String xml, java.lang.String xml2) {
    println("xml="+xml);
    println("xml2="+xml2);
    return "GetObjectName";
}
```

Java code that executes the call here:

```
    ...
    String dmpExec=null;            
        engine.getContext().setAttribute("dmp", dmpExec, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
        engine.eval(fileContents2.toString());
    Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;    
    String function="GetObjectName";  
        System.out.println("function="+function);
        Object ret = (Object)inv.invokeFunction(function, "param1", "param2");
    ...
```

For reference full Java code here: https://pastebin.com/QaWEDUg3

Comment: JDK8 and groovy 2.4.6, the code works fine, so maybe a version problem?